# PhoneGap UITableView/ListView efficiency?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cordova, android-listview

Instead of creating one app twice on two platforms (iOS & Android), I am looking for an alternative (i.e. PhoneGap) to build an app for my client.

It is a very much traditional CRUD app with lots of forms. The main concern is search and scroll efficiency of UITableView/ListView.

I am not looking for Facebook-like optimization. I wish the users does not *feel* it is significantly slower than a native app.

Is there a sample app out there which (lazily)-loads a PhoneGap equivalent UITableView from a Sqlite table with thousands of items?

What kind of speed downgrade will I expect from using PhoneGap instead of the naive UITableView/ListView?

Comment: You can have look at the [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) which is from dojo toolkit but an independent module.

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at the [dgrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/) which is from dojo but an independent module.